# How to connect to google sheets from within AI Notebooks in GCP when both the modules are in same project?

Tags: google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I would like to read and write data to google drive from my google cloud console's AI Notebook. I am currently aware of how to read data from google spreadsheets through my local Python console (using gspread and oauth2client libraries).

I know that I can access bigquery data from AI notebooks using pandas_gbq **without providing any credentials.** Is there any similar method for google sheets as well?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "without providing any credential"? Without have a JSON key file?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yes, without the JSON key file - sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: Do you actually need to access the spreadsheet without credentials? You cannot use the API without authentication, what you can do instead is directly getting the sheet through a HTTP request if it is public. But you won't be able to modify it.